# ruby on rails: How to display error messages in a view with multi-model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can show the errors of model: `Tester`, but can't show the error of model: `HourlyPay` on the view. How can I show errors of model: `HourlyPay` on `Tester` view.

My models are as below:

Model: `HourlyPay`

```
class HourlyPay < ActiveRecord::Base
  require "pp"
  belongs_to :tester
  default_scope { order(:update_date) }
  validate :validate_amount

  def validate_amount
    pp "Check amout"
    if new_record? && amount.nil?
        errors.add(:amount, "を入力してください。")
        pp errors
        pp HourlyPay
    end   
  end
end
```

Model: `Tester`

```
class Tester < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SearchHelper

  belongs_to :partner

  has_many :hourly_pay
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hourly_pay
end
```

my view: Tester

```
<%= form_for(@tester) do |f| %>
  <table class='ta1'>
    <% if @tester.errors.any? %>
      <tr id="error_explanation">
      <th class="tamidashi" colspan="2"><ul>
      <% @tester.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      <% @tester.errors[:hourly_pay].full_messages.each do |message| %>     
        <li><%= error %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul></th></tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```